# TPMS Replacement

Tags: replace, tire-pressure-monitoring-system

I am replacing rim and tires (26,000 miles on tires) on my 2016 Ford F150. About 3 months ago my right rear was showing 22 lbs and I reset the TPMS and it was showing 35 but when hot it is showing 39 to 40 and the other 3 are showing 37 to 38. Should I replace all 4 TPMS's?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! IIRC, the TPMS transmitters are supposed to be good for 10 years ... not sure why yours would be going bad already. (I could be wrong on this ... getting old ... memory fading :o)

Comment: Have you tried checking the actual pressure with a good quality manual gauge?  Even if your gauge pressure reads higher or lower than what the TPMS claims, see if the relative differences are the same between the right rear and the other 3 tires.